# stop push to existing git-lab but push to new git hub repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I want to stop pushing my-project into my existing git-lab repository but want to push it into my different git-hub repository. how do i do please help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+another+repository

Comment: `git remote add` + `git push`

Answer (score 1):

Hey you could use [GitHub Desktop](http://desktop.github.com/). There you can better see, where your project is hosted and change the repository hosting to github in the settings (if already created this repository on github and connected vs code with github?). Do you work with Angular or React?